# How can i run my vuzix android glass app in android studio emulator?

Tags: vuzix, vuzixm100

I am developing a glass app for vuzix m100, blade and m300. I don't have any hardware-glass to run and check the app. How can run app using emulator in android studio?

I tried all steps in developer support portal of vuzix.

Comment: @Thillai may I ask how could you start the first template application? I just started to work on  it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For M300 first, you have to add https://www.vuzix.com/k79g75yXoS/addon.xml and https://www.vuzix.com/M300SDK/M300_addon.xml to your SDK update sites in the android studio then install vuzix device profiles and vuzix m300 extras from sdk tools.Now you can create an emulator for m300 device from avd manager.

Comment: Did you face any issue while adding the second addon (https://www.vuzix.com/M300SDK/M300_addon.xml) in SDK Update Site? I can see this XML redirects me to Access Denied Error on the web browser and  Disabled (red exclamation) on Android Studio's SDK update Site window. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For Vuzix M400 and M4000, Vuzix publishes AVD Device Manager profiles.

https://www.vuzix.com/Download/DownloadDriver?name=/Content/Upload/vuzix-m400.xml

https://www.vuzix.com/Download/DownloadDriver?name=/Content/Upload/vuzix-m4000.xml

You can import these and verify the layouts before you compile, and you can test your app on your emulator. You can navigate the app using the keyboard to generate DPAD navigation instead of using the device physical buttons.